# Network is unreachable only the first time - 18.04

Tags: networking, internet, dns

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 on [System 76 Darter Pro](https://system76.com/laptops/darter) hardware.  Recently, I have had problems with network operations.  The first time I ping a host outside my house, it fails with the message

> connect: Network is unreachable.

Usually the second time I ping, it works fine.  Once in a while the second time doesn't work either, but the third time works.  Ping on that host usually works for a while after that.  But sometimes it will fail again, but only once or twice.

Also, sometimes when I open a website in a new tab, it doesn't find the server.  When I reload, it works.

I am connected with WiFi and here is the WiFi section of `ifconifg`:

```
wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.13  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::bd86:2e6:c418:cb22  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 18:56:80:53:41:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 350585  bytes 433993855 (433.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 91925  bytes 14397443 (14.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have only tried this a couple of times, but it seems like when I ping an IP address (8.8.8.8), it works the first time.  So I am suspicious it may be related to name resolution.

I have an IP address and ping works after the first time, so I don't see the obvious problems.  The network is there and works most of the time.

As I thought it was a router issue, I used a machine with CentOS but cannot reproduce the issue there.  And I had this same problem when I was connected to someone else's WiFi.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: I am seeing this same behavior on both a laptop and a VM.  lspci on the laptop gives: 00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df0 (rev 30).  On the VM there is nothing with the word network, but there is an ethernet: 03:00.0 Ethernet controller: VMware VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller (rev 01).

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it stands all by itself and the next person to come around that has a clue (I Don't have an Intel) will see this valuable information without having to read all of the comments.